# Как можно упростить регулярное выражение на PHP

Tags: php

```
$pattern = '/<img[^>]*\bsrc\s*=\s*["\']([^"\']+)["\']/';
```

```
$preg = preg_match_all($pattern, $text, $matches);
```

У меня есть много разных больших текстов около 15 миллионов символов.Я использую `preg_match_all` для того, чтобы достать путь, вида: data:.... .Хотелось бы упростить регулярное выражение, потому что `preg_match_all` не срабатывает на некоторые текста. Есть возможность, например искать не тег img, а просто src и в нем уже достать путь, без тега img.

Comment: Для этого используют не регулярные выражения, а библиотеки работы с DOM деревом, например https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php   .... так что нет смысла упрощать то, что изначально не предназначено для этих действий

Comment: Если выражение "не срабатывает", то изменить его, чтобы "срабатывало" не называется словом "упростить". Я понимаю, что не для всех пользователей сайта русский язык является родным, но тем не менее, без нормального владения языком вы просто не сможете задать вопрос, и он автоматически отправится в корзину.

Comment: @Ипатьев не стоит придираться к словам, если вы не понимаете суть того, что я написал. Если вы не понимаете о чем я говорю, то уточните это у меня не упрекая. Слово упростить явно указывает на то, что паттерн для preg_match_all сложный и не справляется с большим количеством символов...

Comment: У вас какая-то каша в голове. Сложность паттерна не имеет отношения к количеству символов. Плюс вы **вообще спрашивали про другое:** "как искать не тег img, а просто src". То есть вам надо не упростить, а изменить.